# Image.Save(..) throws a GDI+ exception

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am receiving an image from the user and want to save it.
Initially I do

```
Stream file = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
```

Then perform the save where `file` from the previous step is passed in

```
using(var image = Image.FromStream(file)) {
    // Set the codec parameters with another method. No Stream involved
    image.Save(filename, codecInfo, codeParam); // Throws GDI+ exception
}
```

Exception type is : `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException`

Exception Message : `A generic error occurred in GDI+`

StackTrace:

```
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
```

Have referred other questions where new stream had to be created and kept open but in my case, I already have a input stream. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Which GDI+ exception? Is there a message?

Comment: So it's perhaps `codecInfo` and `codeParam` which cause the issue.

Comment: This exception is questioned so many times on StackOverflow, go check out older questions about the topic please.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried different encoder paramaters, different paths but same exception was thrown. It worked for me to save the image first to a memorystream then to a file stream.
Here's a snippet.

```
   using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   using(FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
   image.Save(memoryStream, yourEncoder, yourEncoderParamaters);
   byte[] imgArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
   fileStream.Write(imgArray, 0, imgArray.Length);
   }
```